# gradle creating build directory in subfolder

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-project

I have a subfolder `api` which holds multiple api related subprojects. I have included an api subproject in my settings.gradle as

```
include "api:invenio"
project(":api:invenio").name = 'metadata-api-invenio'
```

folder structure looks like this
root/api/invenio/build.gradle

For some reason gradle is treating `api` as a subproject as well even though this is just a folder to hold subprojects. Its creating a build directory in api folder. How can I tell gradle to exclude api folder from subprojects.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that it just work that way.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Gradle's [settings.gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/settings.gradle.kts) for an example. Basically you can do somethings like

```
include 'invenio'
project(':invenio').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'api/invenio')
```

Comment: The attached link is inactive.